# Scipy Rotvec to Extrinsic Euler

Tags: python, numpy, math, scipy, rotation

I have rotations of a rigidbody in axis angle format and would like to recover body's yaw in global frame (extrinsic). I use scipy Rotations module as follows:

```
from scipy.spatial.transform import Rotation

axis_angle = #some axis * angle vector
r = Rotation.from_rotvec(axis_angle)
```

However, I am not sure whether:

```
yaw, _, _  = r.as_euler('zyx')

# or 

_, _, yaw = r.as_euler('zyx')
```

As a follow up, would the indexing change if I was looking for intrinsic rotations instead? eg.

```
_, _, yaw = r.as_euler('ZYX')
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The order of angles matches the order of the specified axis sequence.

```py
In [31]: from scipy.spatial.transform import Rotation as R

In [32]: R.from_euler('Z', 45, degrees=True).as_euler('zyx', degrees=True)
Out[32]: array([45.,  0.,  0.])

In [33]: R.from_euler('Z', 45, degrees=True).as_euler('ZYX', degrees=True)
Out[33]: array([45.,  0.,  0.])

In [34]: R.from_euler('Y', 45, degrees=True).as_euler('ZYX', degrees=True)
Out[34]: array([ 0., 45.,  0.])

In [35]: R.from_euler('X', 45, degrees=True).as_euler('ZYX', degrees=True)
Out[35]: array([ 0.,  0., 45.])

In [36]: R.from_euler('X', 45, degrees=True).as_euler('zyx', degrees=True)
Out[36]: array([ 0.,  0., 45.])
```

I can't find anywhere in the [Scipy docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.transform.Rotation.html#scipy-spatial-transform-rotation) where it is explicitly stated that the order of angles matches the order of the axis sequence.  I'm not sure this is a major deficiency: it seems reasonable that they would match.